# Node-Red function editor dialogs not updating when I type

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red

I can't see what I am typing or pasting into some Node-Red text boxes when editing nodes. For example, the Function property of the function node or the Body property of the comment node.

If I Ok the unseen edits and then double-click the node again, I can see that my edits were made.

I can see what I am typing into other properties such as the Name of the function node or the Title of the comment node.

I notice that this behaviour affects multi-line text boxes rather than single-line text boxes.

Comment: Could you show us via e.g. images or code what you mean? If this is not specifically about programming, your question is off-topic on this specific site, but may be on-topic on other sites in the [Stack Exchange network](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology).

Comment: You may do better asking this on the Node-RED mailing list, where we can have some back and forth to debug the issue. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the Iceweasel browser and then the editor dialogs updated when typing. The problem is with the Epiphany browser.